# Oracle SQL Return all records within days of date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, days

I am hoping that somebody can help me out with this question.

The following SQL returns just the records in a given table that are specifically 20 days from current.

Last_Mod_Date = TO_DATE(SYSDATE - 20)

Using similar theory can somebody help me determine how to return all records within the past 20 days range?

Thanks!

Comment: Last_Mod_Date > TO_DATE(SYSDATE - 20) ?

Comment: In your example **Last_Mod_date = TO_DATE(SYSDATE - 20)** is very unlikely to match anything because it says "exactly 20 days from now" (to the millisecond)  A weaker form that perhaps is closer to what you want is **"TRUNC(Last_Mod_date) = TRUNC(TO_DATE(SYSDATE - 20))"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  *
from
  table
where
  Last_Mod_Date >= trunc(sysdate-20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE TO_DATE(my_ts_field) BETWEEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE-20) AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the comparison to greater-than-or-equal:

```
Last_Mod_Date >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-20)
```

Comment: hmm, good point.  I just copied it from the original question, but of course the TO_DATE is not necessary.  Although perhaps it is effectively performing a TRUNC, so removing it could change the results somewhat.